# field validation in atk4

Tags: atk4

I remember a post from Romans pointing out different methods (3) of field validation in agile toolkit forms. Desperately searching but can't find it anywhere.

Anybody how can help me ?

Tks a lot

Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 3 methods:
http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/form/validation

Comment: And that's form validation only. You can also validate in the model: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/model/actions